# How to print null terminating character \0 for a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null

In C suppose you have the following:

```
char * myString = "EMMA";
```

How do you print out `myString[4]` and get `\0`?

Comment: Print the integer value: `printf("%d\n", mytring[4]);` ... compare with `printf("%c=%d\n", myString[1], myString[1])`

Comment: @pmg that just gets me 0.  How do you know if it's 0 or \0?

Comment: There is no difference between `0` and `'\0'`. They are absolutely 100% identical except in source form (in text).

Comment: `0` and `'\0'` are both zero. Even the type is the same (`int`) in C (they differ in C++).

Comment: @Acorn:the type of `0` and `'\0'` is the same: `int`. The type of `myString[4]` is `char` ... but you cannot pass a char into printf anyway: it always gets converted to int

Comment: @pmg Yeah, I thought this was a C++ question :)

Comment: @Acorn you don't terminate a pointer with 0 you terminate it with \0 so they are different.  How do you know if your string contains 0 or it's been ended with \0?  While I know how to check is there a way to print out the \0 directly with printf?

Comment: Did you tried using `printf("%c", myString[4]);`? And what is the purpose of wanting this? What do you mean with "get" exactly?

Comment: I did try the %c you get a blank.  I mean with "get" print out to the terminal \0

Comment: @DCR "*you don't terminate a pointer with 0 you terminate it with \0 so they are different*" - You don't terminate pointers at all. "*How do you know if your string contains 0 or it's been ended with \0?*" Because it's a string literal if its surrounded by `""` and its guaranteed.

Comment: @DCR Then `printf("%d", myString[4]);` is the right way.

Comment: @"RobertS supports Monica Cellio" all pointers are terminated with \0.  How else would you know where they end.

Comment: @DCR Pointers are pointers. They just store address values of the objects they *point* to. What you mean is the string literal.

Comment: fair point. thanks for your help

Comment: @DCR: C character strings are terminated with 0. ("A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string"). You can write that as `\0` but that's no different from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your own function to print not printable characters in the form of **`C escape chars`**.

```
void myprint(const char *str)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("str[%4zu]=", n++);
        switch(*str)
        {
            case '\0':
                printf("`\\0`\n");
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("`\\n`\n");
                break;
            case '\r':
                printf("`\\r`\n");
                break;
            case '\b':
                printf("`\\b`\n");
                break;
            case '\t':
                printf("`\\t`\n");
                break;
            case '\v':
                printf("`\\v`\n");
                break;
            default:
                if(isprint((unsigned char) *str))
                    printf("'%c'\n", *str);
                else
                    printf("'\\x%02hhx'\n", *str);
        }
    }while(*str++);
}

int main(void)
{
    myprint("Te\xf0st\t\n\r");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WahMbb

Answer (score 2):

`0` is the code for `'\0'` and since in C `char` types are in reality `int` types, in this context they are the same.

`'\0'` is a non-printable character or if you prefer a non-printable control signal.

That said you can print its code using:

```
printf("%d", myString[4]);
```

This will print, of course, `0`.

If you want to print the actual `'\0'` you can do it with a simple condition:

```
const char* nulchar = "\\0";

if(myString[4] == 0)
    printf("%s", nulchar);
```

Comment: your if condition is incorrect.  It should be ...== '\0'  Noy ...=='0' which is my basic point.  Odd that there is not a direct way to do this

Comment: @DCR `0` and `'\0'` are the same.

Comment: @DCR, it's meant to be non printable, like all the characters in the ASCII table from 0 to 31, and also the 127 which is the delete signal.

Comment: @DCR Update: Their notation is of course different (plain `int` vs. character) but the value gained is the same. So it makes no difference at the comparison.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio, yes, of couse, but in the context of a comparison they are compared as `int`, which is what they really are.

Comment: @anastaciu Didn't complained anything about it :-) Clarified my previous comment.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio, yes, and I upvoted both :).

Comment: @anastaciu You can omit the `if` condition test completely since it's guarranteed that each string literal has to end with a NUL byte. By doing so you also have no issues when the string literal pointed to changes.

Comment: @DCR Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548683/how-to-print-null-terminating-character-0-for-a-pointer/63549434#comment112373391_63549078) again.

Comment: @DCR The value gained with `myString[4]` and `'\0'` is `0` of type `int`. `0 == 0` = `1`.

Answer (score 1):

> "I did try the `%c` you get a blank. I mean with "get" print out to the terminal \0."

Printing `'\0'` with `%c` always gets you no visible output because `'\0'` is an escape sequence and not printable.

---

The C standard guarantees that each string literal ends with a NUL byte:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.
>
> C18, §6.4.5/6

So practically, you can just do

```
const char * myString = "EMMA";

fputs(myString, stdin);
puts("\\0");
```

or the `printf()` variant:

```
const char * myString = "EMMA";

printf("%s%s\n", myString, "\\0");
```

if you just want to print out `\0` after the string, which also maintains safety when the string literal `myString` point to, changes.

Output (with both variants):

```
EMMA\0
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way:

```
write(1, myString + 4, 1);
```

portable way:

```
fwrite(mystring + 4, 1, 1, stdout);
```

Comment: can you do this using printf?

Comment: @DCR: `printf("%c", myString[4]);` might work but it's not clearly defined to work. I can just see printf filling an internal buffer and sending out via fputs ...

Comment: tested  your answer and they both return nothing

Comment: @DCR, nul has no glyph. Try piping output to hexdump.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @DCR: `./a.out | hexdump`

Comment: "easy way:`write(1, myString + 4, 1);`" -->  `write()` in not in the standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no printable character associated with the terminator (that’s why it’s used as the terminator, it’s not a "normal" character value).

The *character* `'0'` has a non-zero encoding (48 in ASCII).

If you want to display a trailing `0` or `\0` following the string, the you’ll need to employ some trickery like the following:

```
printf( "%s\\%d\n", mystring, mystring[ strlen(mystring) ] );
```

should output `EMMA\0`.

Answer (score -1):

using `%s` in `printf` as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * myString = "EMMA";
    
    printf("myString[4]=%s", myString[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

you get:

```
myString[4]=(null)
```

but... with the following warning:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
```

So, if it's only a quick and dirty way to see the "NULL" printed out, could be enough.

Comment: Why recommend using the `%s` format for an *integer* argument? Other answers have shown a better (correct) way to print the terminal "zero".